# How to read every 2nd like of a csv file in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I have a tab-separated CSV file and I want to read every 2nd line. How can I configure it in Logstash? I am preferring the CSV filter but in the documentation, I can't really find any way to do it. is there any way?

Comment: Hi, does every second line as a separate pattern to identify? Did you mean every alternate line here? PS: its "LOGSTASH"

Comment: Yes every 2nd line contains a value called "POWER" ins a tab separated column

Comment: @Ankit could you help please ?

Comment: Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you input provided in the comments :

```
filter {
    if [message] =~ /POWER/ {
      csv {
          separator => "        "
          <other csv filter configurations>
      }
    }
    else {
      drop {}
    }
}
```

Comment: the text ( value ) match can be done  like /POWER/  or "POWER" ?

Comment: when you wanna check for a substring, /POWER/ will work. @AnonymousScientificUser